# Unable to connect to Magento admin panel

Tags: magento

I have an issue with Magneto community and we are using "bizarre" theme. Everything was working fine till last night and I was modifying the categories and products, today morning it seems that there's some issue with admin panel.

When I am logging in with my user id password, it takes me to the index page every time not to admin panel, it works for a while but when I try to go to any settings like "system>configuration> etc" it takes me again to the main page of the website (frontend).

Comment: Can you mention the changes you did earlier ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with cache management.

Try to delete `var` folder in the `[YOUR SITE PATH HERE]/magento/var`

Additionally, it might be useful to you. Here is [`3 ways to turn on/off cache in Magento`](http://www.antonoffplus.com/3-ways-to-turn-onoff-cache-in-magento/)